# In Arangodb how to do multi upsert in single for loop

Tags: arangodb, aql

I expected to run both upsert

```
for i in [1,2]
upsert { _key: i } insert {v:i} update{} in Test
upsert { _key: i*100 } insert {v:i*100} update{} in Test
```

But I got

```
Query: variable '$OLD' is assigned multiple times (while parsing)
```

Version: 3.1.14

**EDIT**

In real query , what I want to do is something like this

```
FOR n IN MyData
FILTER n.person
    FOR p IN n.person
    UPSERT { _key: p.id } INSERT { _key:p.id, name:p.name} UPDATE {} IN Person
    UPSERT { _from:CONCAT('Person/',p.id),_to:CONCAT('Other/',n.id) }
    INSERT { _from:CONCAT('Person/',p.id),_to:CONCAT('Other/',n.id), type: n.type }  
    UPDATE {} IN PersonRelation
```

Have ever arangodb consider there will be multi upsert ?

Currently, I have to run query one by one, the dataset is big, so, it's very slow to just run one upsert a time. Maybe I should use `INSERT`  and `ignoreErrors`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this error is happening because you are writing to the collection twice and the query optimizer won't let you do it.

Another solution is to write the same content, still using an `UPSERT` command, but shuffle it around a bit so you are only writing once.

This example works:

```
LET new_documents = FLATTEN(FOR i IN [1,2] RETURN [{_key: TO_STRING(i), v:i},{ _key: TO_STRING(i*100), v:i*100 } ])
FOR doc IN new_documents
    UPSERT { _key: doc._key } INSERT { _key: doc._key, v: doc.v } UPDATE{} IN Test
    RETURN {
        new_entries: NEW,
        old_entries: OLD
   }
```

A few notes:

- A `new_documents` variable is created and it contains the records you want to add.
- The results of `new_documents` goes through `FLATTEN` to turn it into a flat array of objects.
- The `_key` of each document is converted to a string, as a _key must be a string
- Then loop through that flattened array, and perform your `UPSERT` on each member of array
- Access the output variables `NEW` and `OLD` which are free output variables from the `UPSERT` command.

The `NEW` variable can be very useful if you were inserting new records and the `_key` value was being generated automatically. By looking at the `NEW` variable you can fetch the `_key`s of all the new documents you just added, if you added them at all.

#### Update

To support your updated question, you can still perform multiple `UPSERT`s by isolating them in a variable definition, like this:

```
FOR n IN myData
FILTER n.v
    LET test = (UPSERT { _key: n.v } INSERT { _key: n.v, v: n.v } UPDATE {} IN Test)
    LET test2 = (UPSERT { _key: n.v } INSERT { _key: n.v, v: n.v } UPDATE {} IN Test2)
    RETURN {
        done: true
    }
```

This query reads documents from `myData` and then based on that performs `UPSERT` commands into the collections `Test` and `Test2`.

That should help you with your data model, just make sure the value you use as the `_key` for the new documents is a string.

Comment: The `for i in [1,2]` is only used for demonstration.In real query , it's more complicated, A few upsert for different collection, I will update the question to include the query.